# pandas read csv with missing column names and unequal row size

Tags: pandas, python-3.11

I have a csv file `myFile.csv` with the contents as follows:

[image]

The top tow is column header. So, the column names are missing for B, C, F, G, H

I am trying the following:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', usecols=range(0,8))
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: [0, 1, 2,
```

I should get the following after successful read:

```
df1.columns
Index(['id', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'To', 'DD',, 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7'],
```

Edit:

Data is:

```
id,,,To,DD,,,
1,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,
4,NA,NA,NA,NA,45,NA,NA
5,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,
6,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,
```

Comment: Please provide your input example **as text**

Comment: `df1 = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv')` should work.